# Stuck with scrapy following imgur links from subreddits

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping reddit to get the link of every entry in a subreddit. And I would like to follow the links that match `http://imgur.com/gallery/\w*` too. But I'm having problems to run the callback for Imgur. It just doesn't execute it. What's failing ?

And I'm detecting the Imgur url with a simple `if "http://imgur.com/gallery/" in item['link'][0]:` statement, maybe scrapy provides a better way to detect them ?

This is what I tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from reddit.items import RedditItem


class RedditSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "reddit"
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics",
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['/r/pics/\?count=\d.*&after=\w.*']),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        )
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'entry')]/p/a"):
            item = RedditItem()
            item['title'] = title.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['link'] = title.xpath('@href').extract()

            yield item

            if "http://imgur.com/gallery/" in item['link'][0]:
                # print item['link'][0]
                url = response.urljoin(item['link'][0])
                print url
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_imgur_gallery)

    def parse_imgur_gallery(self, response):
        print response.url
```

This is my Item class:

```
import scrapy


class RedditItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

This is the output when executing the spider with `--nolog` and printing the `url` variable inside the if condition (It's not the `response.url` var output), It still doesn't run the callback:

```
PS C:\repos\python\scrapy\reddit> scrapy crawl --output=export.json --nolog reddit
http://imgur.com/gallery/W7sXs/new
http://imgur.com/gallery/v26KnSX
http://imgur.com/gallery/fqqBq
http://imgur.com/gallery/9GDTP/new
http://imgur.com/gallery/5gjLCPV
http://imgur.com/gallery/l6Tpavl
http://imgur.com/gallery/Ow4gQ
...
```

Comment: Are you sure the hrefs are what you expect them to be in the source code?

Comment: Yeah `item['link'][0]` and also the `url` var return the url string. I've executed it by cmd with `--nolog` and It return the correct imgur urls.

Comment: Didn't knew about it. Thanks for pointing it. https://www.reddit.com/dev/api But I was trying to learn more about scrapy I was using reddit as a playground for my tests... I still would like to learn to follow links from other sources but taken from the `start_urls` (using LinkExtractor) ie. imgur urls taken from subreddit page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found It. The `imgur.com` domain wasn't allowed. Just needed to add it...

```
allowed_domains = ["reddit.com", "imgur.com"]
```